# T-Sql xml query with namespace

Tags: xml, t-sql

This is a follow up question to

[T-Sql xml query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8909711/t-sql-xml-query)

If I add a namespace to xml data, nothing is returned again.

```
DECLARE @xVar XML
SET @xVar = 
  '<ReportData ObjectId="123" xmlns="http://ait.com/reportdata">
  <ReportId>AAAA-BBBB-CCCCC-DDDDD</ReportId>
  <DocId>100</DocId>
  <ReportName>Drag Scraper Troubleshooting</ReportName>
  <DocType>Name</DocType>
  <StatusId>1</StatusId>
  <AuthorId>1</AuthorId>
   </ReportData>'

SELECT [ReportId]= reportdata.item.value('.', 'varchar(40)') 
FROM   @xVar.nodes('/ReportData/ReportId[1]') AS reportdata(item)
```

The above query returns nothing. Secondly, how would I select all elements in a single select and return a row with all elements as fields?

I want to return a record constructed as the following:

```
ReportId              | DocId | ReportName | 
AAAA-BBBB-CCCCC-DDDDD | 100   | AAAA-BBBB-CCCCC-DDDDD |
```

Comment: Could you maybe rephrase the question a bit? Assuming you have multiple ReportData elements, you want to return the elements as separate columns? Am I right in assuming that?

Comment: Modified my question a bit, hope it helps

Comment: Not even an up-vote for my valid contribution? :(

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Look at [`WITH XMLNAMESPACES`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177400.aspx)

```
;WITH XMLNAMESPACES(DEFAULT 'http://ait.com/reportdata')
SELECT [ReportId]= reportdata.item.value('.', 'varchar(40)') 
FROM   @xVar.nodes('/ReportData/ReportId[1]') AS reportdata(item)
```

Comment: Thanks again, for those who are interested in final version:  WITH XMLNAMESPACES(DEFAULT 'http://ait.com/reportdata') 
SELECT [ReportId]= reportdata.item.value('./ReportId[1]', 'varchar(40)') , 
[DocId]= reportdata.item.value('./DocId[1]', 'varchar(40)')  
FROM   @xVar.nodes('/ReportData') AS reportdata(item). I wish i could give tribute to both answers her but not sure you can do that

Answer (score 4):

If you are trying to extract data and the namespace might differ between records, you can use a wildcard for the namespace prefix. Just put "*:" before each element name in the last line of the OP's original code, like this:

```
FROM   @xVar.nodes('/*:ReportData/*:ReportId[1]') AS reportdata(item)
```

Note that you need to use the wildcard at every level, not just at the same level as you see a namespace declaration in the xml. This is because namespaces are inherited by each level from the level above it.

Comment: you re a life saver!

Answer (score 2):

If my assumptions are correct and you want to list ALL ReportData elements in your XML document and want their child elements as different columns, you could look at something like this:

```
;WITH XMLNAMESPACES(DEFAULT 'http://ait.com/reportdata')
SELECT 
    [ReportId] = reportdata.item.value('(./ReportId)[1]', 'varchar(40)') 
  , [DocId] = reportdata.item.value('(./DocId)[1]', 'varchar(40)') 
  , [ReportName] = reportdata.item.value('(./ReportName)[1]', 'varchar(40)') 
  , [DocType] = reportdata.item.value('(./DocType)[1]', 'varchar(40)') 
  , [StatusId] = reportdata.item.value('(./StatusId)[1]', 'varchar(40)') 
  , [AuthorId] = reportdata.item.value('(./AuthorId)[1]', 'varchar(40)') 
FROM @xVar.nodes('//ReportData') AS reportdata(item)
```

I'll need to look at cleaning up the namespace declarations a bit, but it seems to work for me...

EDIT: Amended my answer with the WITH XMLNAMESPACES clause as recommended by Martin. :)

Comment: thanks , works for me too. If we only could get rid of those pesky namespace statements

Comment: I have seen there is a WITH XMLNAMESPACES statement , but i cant seem to get it to work

Comment: @user1071785 - er, My answer has a working example with that (?)

Comment: OK, amended my answer to include Martin's suggestion for the WITH XMLNAMESPACES clause... Hope it works out for you!

Comment: Thanks, i wish i could give tribute to both of you

Comment: @klashagelqvist - You can! You can upvote helpful answers by clicking the up arrow to the left as well...