# How to declare xml namespace in sql?

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml

This is a follow up question to [T-Sql xml query with namespace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8909987/t-sql-xml-query-with-namespace)

I have the following XML data.I need to convert it into a SQL table.I used the following SQL query:

```
 declare @XML xml =
    '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RS xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-analysis:rowset">
        <xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:saw-sql="urn:saw-sql" targetNamespace="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-analysis:rowset">
            <xsd:complexType name="R">
                <xsd:sequence>
                    <xsd:element name="C0" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" saw-sql:type="varchar" saw-sql:sqlFormula="&quot;CBR&quot;.&quot;Product Binary&quot;.&quot;Binary Name&quot;" saw-sql:displayFormula="&quot;Product Binary&quot;.&quot;Binary Name&quot;" saw-sql:aggregationRule="none" saw-sql:aggregationType="nonAgg" saw-sql:tableHeading="Product Binary" saw-sql:columnHeading="Binary Name" saw-sql:columnID="ca5ff07f42dfb3ea1"/>
                    <xsd:element name="C1" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" saw-sql:type="varchar" saw-sql:sqlFormula="&quot;CBR&quot;.&quot;Product Binary&quot;.&quot;Download Display Name&quot;" saw-sql:displayFormula="&quot;Product Binary&quot;.&quot;Download Display Name&quot;" saw-sql:aggregationRule="none" saw-sql:aggregationType="nonAgg" saw-sql:tableHeading="Product Binary" saw-sql:columnHeading="Download Display Name" saw-sql:columnID="c1f02dadb0dfa49a0"/>
                    <xsd:element name="C2" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" saw-sql:type="varchar" saw-sql:sqlFormula="&quot;CBR&quot;.&quot;Download Start Date&quot;.&quot;Quarter&quot;" saw-sql:displayFormula="&quot;Download Start Date&quot;.&quot;Quarter&quot;" saw-sql:aggregationRule="none" saw-sql:aggregationType="nonAgg" saw-sql:tableHeading="Download Start Date" saw-sql:columnHeading="Quarter" saw-sql:columnID="c66bc4e116b33b4ef"/>
                    <xsd:element name="C3" type="xsd:date" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" saw-sql:type="date" saw-sql:sqlFormula="&quot;CBR&quot;.&quot;Download Start Date&quot;.&quot;Cal Date&quot;" saw-sql:displayFormula="&quot;Download Start Date&quot;.&quot;Cal Date&quot;" saw-sql:aggregationRule="none" saw-sql:aggregationType="nonAgg" saw-sql:tableHeading="Download Start Date" saw-sql:columnHeading="Cal Date" saw-sql:columnID="c5bb40fa14f988e4a"/>
                    <xsd:element name="C4" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" saw-sql:type="varchar" saw-sql:sqlFormula="&quot;CBR&quot;.&quot;Download Start Date&quot;.&quot;Week&quot;" saw-sql:displayFormula="&quot;Download Start Date&quot;.&quot;Week&quot;" saw-sql:aggregationRule="none" saw-sql:aggregationType="nonAgg" saw-sql:tableHeading="Download Start Date" saw-sql:columnHeading="Week" saw-sql:columnID="ce8ad46904662e816"/>
                    <xsd:element name="C5" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" saw-sql:type="varchar" saw-sql:sqlFormula="&quot;CBR&quot;.&quot;Download Start Date&quot;.&quot;Month&quot;" saw-sql:displayFormula="&quot;Download Start Date&quot;.&quot;Month&quot;" saw-sql:aggregationRule="none" saw-sql:aggregationType="nonAgg" saw-sql:tableHeading="Download Start Date" saw-sql:columnHeading="Month" saw-sql:columnID="ca19e13040145f84b"/>
                    <xsd:element name="C6" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" saw-sql:type="varchar" saw-sql:sqlFormula="&quot;CBR&quot;.&quot;Download Start Date&quot;.&quot;Year&quot;" saw-sql:displayFormula="&quot;Download Start Date&quot;.&quot;Year&quot;" saw-sql:aggregationRule="none" saw-sql:aggregationType="nonAgg" saw-sql:tableHeading="Download Start Date" saw-sql:columnHeading="Year" saw-sql:columnID="cd55ae47d83c209a6"/>
                    <xsd:element name="C7" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" saw-sql:type="varchar" saw-sql:sqlFormula="&quot;CBR&quot;.&quot;Customer Segment&quot;.&quot;Customer Segment&quot;" saw-sql:displayFormula="&quot;Customer Segment&quot;.&quot;Customer Segment&quot;" saw-sql:aggregationRule="none" saw-sql:aggregationType="nonAgg" saw-sql:tableHeading="Customer Segment" saw-sql:columnHeading="Customer Segment" saw-sql:columnID="cebaa8810a3cb8064"/>
                    <xsd:element name="C8" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" saw-sql:type="varchar" saw-sql:sqlFormula="&quot;CBR&quot;.&quot;Customer Contact&quot;.&quot;Customer Type&quot;" saw-sql:displayFormula="&quot;Customer Contact&quot;.&quot;Customer Type&quot;" saw-sql:aggregationRule="none" saw-sql:aggregationType="nonAgg" saw-sql:tableHeading="Customer Contact" saw-sql:columnHeading="Customer Type" saw-sql:columnID="c602557f90d4ad9da"/>
                    <xsd:element name="C9" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" saw-sql:type="varchar" saw-sql:sqlFormula="&quot;CBR&quot;.&quot;Dnb Organization&quot;.&quot;Business Name&quot;" saw-sql:displayFormula="&quot;Dnb Organization&quot;.&quot;Business Name&quot;" saw-sql:aggregationRule="none" saw-sql:aggregationType="nonAgg" saw-sql:tableHeading="Dnb Organization" saw-sql:columnHeading="Business Name" saw-sql:columnID="c5b35569f06cec8ea"/>
                    <xsd:element name="C10" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" saw-sql:type="varchar" saw-sql:sqlFormula="&quot;CBR&quot;.&quot;Dnb Organization&quot;.&quot;Country Region&quot;" saw-sql:displayFormula="&quot;Dnb Organization&quot;.&quot;Country Region&quot;" saw-sql:aggregationRule="none" saw-sql:aggregationType="nonAgg" saw-sql:tableHeading="Dnb Organization" saw-sql:columnHeading="Country Region" saw-sql:columnID="c522eb1b6f5c0fe4d"/>
                    <xsd:element name="C11" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" saw-sql:type="varchar" saw-sql:sqlFormula="&quot;CBR&quot;.&quot;Dnb Organization&quot;.&quot;Country Geo&quot;" saw-sql:displayFormula="&quot;Dnb Organization&quot;.&quot;Country Geo&quot;" saw-sql:aggregationRule="none" saw-sql:aggregationType="nonAgg" saw-sql:tableHeading="Dnb Organization" saw-sql:columnHeading="Country Geo" saw-sql:columnID="c1874f494099b9641"/>
                    <xsd:element name="C12" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" saw-sql:type="varchar" saw-sql:sqlFormula="&quot;CBR&quot;.&quot;Dnb Organization&quot;.&quot;Iso Country Name&quot;" saw-sql:displayFormula="&quot;Dnb Organization&quot;.&quot;Iso Country Name&quot;" saw-sql:aggregationRule="none" saw-sql:aggregationType="nonAgg" saw-sql:tableHeading="Dnb Organization" saw-sql:columnHeading="Iso Country Name" saw-sql:columnID="ceb5291bac5a83a51"/>
                    <xsd:element name="C13" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" saw-sql:type="varchar" saw-sql:sqlFormula="&quot;CBR&quot;.&quot;Customer Contact&quot;.&quot;City Name&quot;" saw-sql:displayFormula="&quot;Customer Contact&quot;.&quot;City Name&quot;" saw-sql:aggregationRule="none" saw-sql:aggregationType="nonAgg" saw-sql:tableHeading="Customer Contact" saw-sql:columnHeading="City Name" saw-sql:columnID="c3fcf2b0a26f2d882"/>
                    <xsd:element name="C14" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" saw-sql:type="varchar" saw-sql:sqlFormula="&quot;CBR&quot;.&quot;Customer Contact&quot;.&quot;Country&quot;" saw-sql:displayFormula="&quot;Customer Contact&quot;.&quot;Country&quot;" saw-sql:aggregationRule="none" saw-sql:aggregationType="nonAgg" saw-sql:tableHeading="Customer Contact" saw-sql:columnHeading="Country" saw-sql:columnID="c62a616664e32a709"/>
                    <xsd:element name="C15" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" saw-sql:type="varchar" saw-sql:sqlFormula="&quot;CBR&quot;.&quot;Customer Contact&quot;.&quot;Last Name&quot;" saw-sql:displayFormula="&quot;Customer Contact&quot;.&quot;Last Name&quot;" saw-sql:aggregationRule="none" saw-sql:aggregationType="nonAgg" saw-sql:tableHeading="Customer Contact" saw-sql:columnHeading="Last Name" saw-sql:columnID="c0651d86673c4e74d"/>
                    <xsd:element name="C16" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" saw-sql:type="varchar" saw-sql:sqlFormula="&quot;CBR&quot;.&quot;Customer Contact&quot;.&quot;First Name&quot;" saw-sql:displayFormula="&quot;Customer Contact&quot;.&quot;First Name&quot;" saw-sql:aggregationRule="none" saw-sql:aggregationType="nonAgg" saw-sql:tableHeading="Customer Contact" saw-sql:columnHeading="First Name" saw-sql:columnID="c9dfc11cb810a623d"/>
                    <xsd:element name="C17" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" saw-sql:type="varchar" saw-sql:sqlFormula="&quot;CBR&quot;.&quot;Customer Contact&quot;.&quot;Email Address&quot;" saw-sql:displayFormula="&quot;Customer Contact&quot;.&quot;Email Address&quot;" saw-sql:aggregationRule="none" saw-sql:aggregationType="nonAgg" saw-sql:tableHeading="Customer Contact" saw-sql:columnHeading="Email Address" saw-sql:columnID="cf7152d03553d4987"/>
                </xsd:sequence>
            </xsd:complexType>
        </xsd:schema>
        <R>
            <C0>/software/vcm/56/VCM-OS-Provisioning-Server-5.6.iso</C0>
            <C1>VMware vCenter Configuration Manager 5.6.0</C1>
            <C2>14Q1</C2>
            <C3>2014-01-02</C3>
            <C4>W01</C4>
            <C5>JANUARY</C5>
            <C6>2014</C6>
            <C7>Enterprise</C7>
            <C8>ESTABLISHED</C8>
            <C9>XCHANGING PLC</C9>
            <C10>NORTHERN EUROPE</C10>
            <C11>EMEA</C11>
            <C12>UNITED KINGDOM</C12>
            <C13>BASILDON</C13>
            <C14>GB</C14>
            <C15>Delves</C15>
            <C16>Craig</C16>
            <C17>craig.delves@xchanging.com</C17>
        </R></RS>'

    declare @SQL nvarchar(max) = ''
    declare @Col nvarchar(max) = ', T.N.value(''[COLNAME][1]'', ''varchar(100)'') as [COLNAME]' 

    ;WITH XMLNAMESPACES( DEFAULT 'urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-analysis:rowset')
    select @SQL = @SQL + replace(@Col, '[COLNAME]', T.N.value('local-name(.)', 'sysname'))
    from @XML.nodes('//R') as T(N)

    set @SQL = 'select '+stuff(@SQL, 1, 2, '')+' from @XML.nodes(''//R'') as T(N)' 

    exec sp_executesql @SQL, N'@XML xml', @XML
```

When I run the query,it returns nothing.Is there a problem with declaring the namespace.Looking for the solution.

Answer (score 1):

You're building a dynamic SQL statement, but the `with xmlnamespaces` part does not make it into the dynamic SQL query.

Note that XPath is case sensitive, so use `//R` instead of `//r`:

```
; with  xmlnamespaces(default 'urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-analysis:rowset')
select  t.n.value('C0[1]', 'varchar(100)') as r 
from    @xml.nodes('//R') as t(n)
```

This prints:

```
/software/vcm/56/VCM-OS-Provisioning-Server-5.6.iso
```

To find a list of all columns, you could:

```
; with  xmlnamespaces(default 'urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-analysis:rowset')
select  T.N.value('local-name(.)', 'sysname')
from    @XML.nodes('//R/child::*') as T(N)
```

This prints:

```
C0
C1
C2
C3
...
```