# Find XML with specific parent node in mssql

Tags: sql-server, xml

I've got table, which contains XML-type column in it. Some of the values in this column begin with

```
<MyAuthenticationParams>
.....
</MyAuthenticationParams>
```

And some with

```
<Sm1AuthenticationParams>
.......
</Sm1AuthenticationParams>
```

How can I select only records with parent node **MyAuthenticationParams**? Thanks for any help.

**EDIT:**
This is how XML looks like

```
    <MyAuthenticationParams xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <AlsoParams> 
    <SecretKey>MVHXAQA5kF4Ab9siV4vPA4aVPn1EKhbqIBrpCZx2Hg</SecretKey>     <DynamicDescriptor />
  </AlsoParams>
  <myParams>
    <AccountName>Acc1</AccountName>
    <Username>testUsername</Username>
   </myParams>
</MyAuthenticationParams>
```

or like this

```
<Sm1AuthenticationParams xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

  <AccountName>XGwzJ6RR</AccountName>

  <SomeNumber>123456780</SomeNumber>
</Sm1AuthenticationParams>
```

Comment: Could you show more of the XML structure?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
a.b.value('NODE_ONE[1]','nvarchar(max)') AS Node_One,
a.b.value('NODE_TWO[1]','nvarchar(max)') AS Node_Two
FROM @MyXML.nodes('XML_MAIN_NODE/MyAuthenticationParams') a(b)
```

Since your XML is in table, use below.

```
SELECT
a.b.value('NODE_ONE[1]','nvarchar(max)') AS Node_One,
a.b.value('NODE_TWO[1]','nvarchar(max)') AS Node_Two
FROM Plans s CROSS APPLY s.Params.nodes('XML_MAIN_NODE/MyAuthenticationParams') a(b)
```

In your case, this works. PATH_TILL_MyAuthenticationParams is the path till the parent node of MyAuthenticationParams tag. 
**`So, if XML is like <root><nodeA><MyAuthenticationParams>...<MyAuthenticationParams><Other_tag></Other_tag></nodeA></root>, PATH_TILL_MyAuthenticationParams is 'root/nodeA'`**

```
DECLARE @xml XML
select @xml = a.b.query('*') FROM Plans s CROSS APPLY s.Params.nodes('PATH_TILL_MyAuthenticationParams') a(b)
PRINT CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX), @xml)

DECLARE @accName NVARCHAR(500)
DECLARE @userName NVARCHAR(500)
DECLARE @secretKey NVARCHAR(2000)
SELECT
@accName = a.b.value('AccountName[1]','nvarchar(max)'),
@userName = a.b.value('Username[1]','nvarchar(max)')
FROM @xml.nodes('MyAuthenticationParams/myParams') a(b)

PRINT @accName
PRINT @userName

SELECT
@secretKey = a.b.value('SecretKey[1]','nvarchar(max)')
FROM @xml.nodes('MyAuthenticationParams/AlsoParams') a(b)
PRINT @secretKey
```

**Edit:**
In a Single Query,

```
DECLARE @AccountName NVARCHAR(500) = ''
DECLARE @Username NVARCHAR(500) = ''
DECLARE @Key VARCHAR(500) = ''

    SELECT @AccountName = x.u.value('(/ROOT_NODE/.../MyAuthenticationParams/myParams/AccountName)[1]', 'nvarchar(max)')
        , @Username = x.u.value('(/ROOT_NODE/.../MyAuthenticationParams/myParams/Username)[1]', 'nvarchar(max)'),
        @Key = x.u.value('(/ROOT_NODE/.../MyAuthenticationParams/AlsoParams/SecretKey)[1]', 'nvarchar(max)')
    FROM Plans a  CROSS APPLY a.Params.nodes('ROOT_NODE') x(u)

    PRINT @AccountName
    PRINT @Username
    PRINT @Key
```

Comment: What is **a** and **b** in this context?

Comment: It's a table valued method. The table (and its columns) returned by a table-valued method need to be aliased. a is for table it creates. c is for column.

Comment: I don't quite understand, how can I use it to table. For example, my table name is Plans and column with xml is Params. Should I declare it to vars somwhere?

Comment: thank you for that, but it's not working. It returns empty columns

Comment: share your xml in the question.

Comment: are you using more namespaces in your XML. If you are using more namespaces, the SQL code will have to be altered.

Comment: Yes, I using more namespaces. But I need to select only XML's with MyAuthenticationParams in parent node.

Comment: If you still get blank columns, include your namespaces for the parent node in the query, and call child nodes through namespaces. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8909987/t-sql-xml-query-with-namespace

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
DECLARE @DataSource XML =
N'
<DataSource>
<parentA>
    <child1></child1>
    <child2></child2>
    <child3></child3>
</parentA>
<parentB>
    <child4></child4>
    <child5></child5>
    <child6></child6>
</parentB>
<parentA>
    <child7></child7>
    <child8></child8>
</parentA>
</DataSource>';


SELECT P.c.query('.')
      ,T.c.query('.')
FROM @DataSource.nodes('DataSource/parentA') P(c)
OUTER APPLY P.c.nodes('*') T(c);
```

[image]

The idea is to use  `nodes` to get all `parentA` nodes (in your case these are the `MyAuthenticationParams` nodes). Then, with second `nodes` we are getting their children but you can whatever you Want from here.