# TSQL XML exists query with namespaces and IF-ELSE condition

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql, xml-namespaces, exists

I want to write T-SQL code that combines the use of the XML `exists()` function with namespaces and an `IF-ELSE` construct.

From [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8910199/973158) I know that `WITH XMLNAMESPACES` is used to use namespaces. I also know that the `exist()` function is used to determine if a node is present in an XML variable.

Until now,  I used `exist()` as follows:

```
IF ((@MyXML.exist('someNode')) = 0)
BEGIN
    -- Do Something
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    -- Do Something else
END
```

However I don't know how to combine this, if I need to use namespaces. I tried as follows, but get an error.

```
;WITH XMLNAMESPACES('http://www.sdmx.org/resources/sdmxml/schemas/v2_1/message' AS ns)
IF ((@MyXML.exist('ns:someNode')) = 0)
BEGIN
    -- Do Something
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    -- Do Something else
END
```

I get the following error:

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'WITH'.

Hence, my question is: how can I use a T-SQL `If-Else` construct in combination with XML namespaces and the XML `exist()` function?

Comment: [Third example in the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/sql/t-sql/xml/exist-method-xml-data-type?view=sql-server-2017#examples).

Comment: thanks that worked. And I learned that namespaces are case-sensitive.

Comment: Everything in XML / XPath / XQuery is case-sensitive... :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You've got one solution by Jeroen already (link to the docs). But - just for fun - I'd like to show you, that there are several ways to go:

```
DECLARE @xml XML=
N'<root xmlns:ns="dummy">
    <ns:test>1</ns:test>
  </root>';
```

--wildcard for the namespace

```
IF @xml.exist('//*:test[text()=1]')=1
    PRINT 'test 1-yes'
ELSE
    PRINT 'test 1-no';
```

--inline declaration (as told you in the docs)

```
IF @xml.exist('declare namespace ns="dummy";//ns:test[text()=1]')=1
    PRINT 'test 2-yes'
ELSE
    PRINT 'test 2-no';
```

--you can use all of the above to set a variable

```
DECLARE @check BIT = @xml.exist('//*:test[text()=1]');
```

--And - if needed - you still can use WITHXMLNAMESPACES like here to set a variable

```
WITH XMLNAMESPACES('dummy' AS ns)
SELECT @check=@xml.exist('//ns:test[text()=1]');

IF @check=1
    PRINT 'test 4-yes'
ELSE
    PRINT 'test 4-no';
```

Altogether this smells a bit *procedural*... Might be, that there is a better approach entirely...